# viewing wifi power spectrum

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, noise

On almost any Windows laptop, I can use the netsh command to see deliberate wifi channels in the 2.4-2.5 GHz wifi band. But, is there a way (without needing further hardware; preferably a free program) to see more of a "real-time power spectrum"? I want the spectrum to include noise (and, for example, someone switching on and off an ad-hoc network before it can broadcast all of its details, or even before it can broadcast a complete packet).

I suspect that all network cards would ignore anything that doesn't come as a complete packet, which is bad for this goal, so I'd like to know what low-level information is available.

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools for different platforms that can do this (one more graphically fancy than the other). [Here is an example of such a site](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21132/change-your-wi-fi-router-channel-to-optimize-your-wireless-signal/). As I'm mainly on Linux and OSX, I have used [Wifi Analyzer](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/37792/wifi-analyzer), [Wifi Scanner](http://accessagility.com/products/wifi-scanner.html) and [iwlist](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iwlist). On Windows, there are two applications that are often used: [InSSIDer](http://www.inssider.com/), which became paind-only recently (bummer!). An alternative (that I have no experience with) is [Xirrus Wifi Inspector](http://www.xirrus.com/Products/Network-Management-and-Software/Network-Management/Wi-Fi-Inspector). Here is a screenshot of the latter:

[image: Xirrus Wifi Inspector screenshot]

And here is one of InSSIDer, which is probably more what you expected:

[image: InSSIDer screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, that's close.  An encrypted channel (assuming I don't have the key and there are no unencrypted
beacons) would never show up with this Windows software though, right?  Do any of your Linux options
allow you to view an encrypted channel's power level?  Ideally, I'd like to get real-time information
for both "energy per bit" and "bits per second", even when all is encrypted.  These programs seem to
effectively only give "energy per bit" for unencrypted bits.

Comment: What do you mean by "encrypted channel"? Simply put, if you need a password for a wifi, then is encrypted, or secure. Those channels are visible on all those tools. A wifi accesspoint may also be hiding his wifi name (not broadcasting it). Maybe this is what you mean? [InSSIDer is able to show encrypted as well as hidden networks](http://www.7tutorials.com/find-hidden-wireless-networks-view-useful-information-including-ssid).

Comment: Yes, I meant a hidden wifi name, but I also meant encryption of all header bits, including the source/destination MAC addresses.  Then, inSSIDer would not be able to know who sent which packet (to plot things in the RSSI plot of your second figure).  I've tried using Acrylic WiFi and it looked like encrypted data packets were totally ignored in the packet detail tab, so that made me think that these encrypted data packets were ignored for the RSSI level too.  So, I wonder if these RSSI plots are only formed from unencrypted packets.

Comment: Then again, I read some sources which say that, even in WPA2, the MAC addresses are usually sent in plaintext (surprising to me!), so I probably need to get this detail clear first.

Comment: And, in my own experiments to check this, I can't turn off my router's periodic unencrypted beacon to conclude anything.

Comment: Mac addresses are always unencrypted; the IP addresses are encrypted but the MACs are not.  Otherwise, any listening wireless network card would have to decrypt every pakket to see if it was addressed to it, before dropping the packet or decrypting and sending the packet up the stack. Maybe you're confusing this with mac address filtering in the router?

Comment: For the record, I just monitored my wifi channel (#6) with Acrylic WiFi in Windows, and then with airport in MacOS, while the other computer was downloading a lot of data via wifi.  None of that heavy data showed up in the pcap files, for either experiment, so I'm concluding that pcap files don't contain encrypted packets.  @agtover - Does this surprise you?  This makes me think the RSSI plots also ignore encrypted packets, as I suspected in my first comment.

Comment: By the way, the pcap files didn't even show a "null packet" line or any indication of a missed/encrypted/ignored packet.  It was as if the other computer didn't download anything.

Comment: Sounds like the wifi card on the capturing side is in [promiscious mode instead of monitor mode](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36997/what-is-the-difference-between-promiscuous-and-monitor-mode-in-wireless-networks). On a side note: I think this discussion is going outside the scope of your initial question. So I suggest you consider accepting this answer and post any following questions as a new question.

Comment: I believe I was in monitor mode.  I will leave this question open for a while since I haven't achieved my goal yet, but will ask a new question to understand why my PCAP file is missing encrypted packets.